# θ波はどういう意味ですか？~What does θ波 mean?

Tags: words, symbols

I've been listening to a couple 勉強用BGM soundtracks lately while I'm studying for any number of things, and I keep seeing this θ波 notation at the end of the title. It finally got to bothering me enough to look up what it meant, and all I could pull up on the thing was that it's a type of brain wave. However, I don't think I'm crazy when I say I still have no idea what that's supposed to mean exactly.
Anyone have any ideas for this one? Cause I sure don't (www)

Comment: Also written `シータ[波]{は}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

θ is Theta, a character from the Greek alphabet that makes the 'th' sound as in 'thin.' It does also describe a type of brain wave . . . and as it happens, 'wave' is the meaning of 波. Now as for what its relevance is, some background music claims to specifically stimulate theta wave production in the brain for enhancing this or that function. Whether or not you believe that's going on is up to you, but essentially these tracks are claiming to have that effect.

Comment: Learn something new everyday! So then would it be pronounced as snailboat commented above, or no?